# Defining nested functions in Python

Tags: python, function, memory-management, nested, time-complexity

I'm working my way through a DataCamp course that has introduced nested functions. The discussion turns to the idea of creating a function inside of another function, like so:

```
def foo(thing):
    def bar(other_thing):
        third_thing = other_thing*2    
        return third_thing
    return bar
```

While I understand the idea of a nested function, isn't it unnecessarily complex to add a function definition inside a function? Shouldn't the function `bar()` be defined *outside* function `foo()` and only *called* inside the function, thus avoiding the wasted time of defining the function `bar()` with each function call of `foo()`? Or does defining the function `bar()` inside function `foo()` save the memory that would be taken up by defining `bar()` globally?

What is the best practice here? ...Or did I basically just outline the two issues and the ultimate method is up to the discretion of the programmer?

Comment: You're missing the key point that `foo()` returns a _function object_.

Comment: I think it totally depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: And this is why opinionated questions aren't necessarily welcome on SO. But all functionality implemented has a purpose, so if you can do it - there's probably a reason why you can/why it was developed. And most of the time it's widely discussed in one of the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/)'s of Python.

Comment: @Torxed My question was predicated on my lack of knowledge of best practices, so I didn't necessarily know if it was fact or opinion.

Comment: Hence why I didn't down vote and just pointed it out that it's generally not welcome. But yes, it's up the programmer to decide when to use those methods and it totally depends on the use case I would say.

Comment: Note that in reasonable uses of this technique, the nested function will typically be using some parameter or local variable defined in the outer function, and therefore the returned nested function will be customized based on that parameter/variable value - not something you could do as easily with a globally-defined function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your function returns a *function*, not a value. The main use of this would be as a closure. Note the subtle change I made here:

```
def foo(thing):
    def bar(other_thing):
        third_thing = other_thing * thing  #  < changed 2 to thing
        return third_thing
    return bar
```

Now calling `foo` with an argument `thing` creates a function `bar`, which multiplies any argument you give it by whatever `thing` was. It behaves like a sort of 'function factory'.

So you can do things likes

```
times_three_function = foo(3)
```

Then `times_three_function(2)`  = 6